# How to use 2.4" TFT LCD Shield with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: display

I have got three questions:

1. How can I use 2.4" TFT LCD Shield** in order to see Raspberry Pi's desktop, and able to touch the screen to control?
2. How can I modify 2.4" TFT LCD Shield** to use it via Raspberry Pi's HDMI port? Is it possible?
3. Is it possible to modify 2.4" TFT LCD Shield** to use it via USB port on Raspberry Pi to see the desktop, and to touch to control?

** *Especially designed for Arduino boards, but I am trying to use it for Raspberry Pi.*

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1) Maybe possible.  You have a lot to learn before you will be able to do that though. 2) Impossible. 3) Impossible.

Answer (score 0):

1. <s>No.</s> Yes, although unjustifiable unless done for the sole purpose of learning. You'll need programming know-how, logic level converters (not necessary) (5v to 3.3v) and [this thingy](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PCF8574.pdf).
2. No.
3. No.

Here are some resources for you: [Parallel to USB](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=14612), [RPi Parallel port](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=23688), [Cursor library in python](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=46653)

It's designed for Arduino. You're gonna need logic-level converters, datasheets/oscilloscope, deep knowledge regarding the pi's GPIO or about the protocols you mentioned (USB and HDMI), maybe some FPGA's and development kits for USB/HDMI, C/C++/Assembler programming knowledge and a high-precision workbench (I'm sure your soldering iron won't do).

Just go get a screen designed for a Pi, and also an Arduino Uno so you can still use that TFT shield :)

Comment: The answer to 1) is unlikely to be a bald no.  However you need to find out if the screen uses a parallel, I2C, or SPI interface, hopefully SPI, and then hunt around for some software to initialise the driver chip and talk graphics primitives to the chip.  Both need a fair bit of experience (if you want to use it with a Pi rather than an Arduino).

Comment: @joan It uses a parallel interface. USB is out of the question while GPIO requires a bit of a learning curve, although tutorials exist for that. Then, he'll have to figure out how the data from the screen is structured (may be sourced from the Arduino screen library). Then, he'll have to port it to use the RPi hardware (Python preferably, since the easy-to-use cursor libraries are in python)

Comment: *parallel and SPI.

Comment: 3-rd statement is Yes - you can attach it throug USB, FYI

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin FYI, you cannot. I have the exact same shield. Did you even check the question and the posted images? OP is referring to directly modifying the screen and not using any intermediate interface like an Arduino.

Comment: @PandaLion98 I checked the images **exactly** =) from the shield's manufacturer's website [take this official code](http://www.mcufriend.com/down/html/?54.html) and take a deep look into your code...

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin There is not a single mention of "USB" in any of the code. The only mention of "USB" in the link you provided is in `UTFT_Requirements.pdf` page 1 footnote 2 which actually refers to connecting the display to a `chipKit Uno` (which is still Arduino-based) which, in turn, is connected to a PC via USB. *I did take a deep look*.

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin Your comment and link further reinforces my comment which states "OP is referring to directly modifying the screen and *not using any intermediate interface like an Arduino*.". I'll go grab dinner now =)

Comment: @PandaLion98 there are *even a stocked solutions* like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=32519&p=280334), [this](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/Arduino-Adapter-For-Raspberry-Pi-p-2443.html) or [this](https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/raspberry-pi-to-arduino-shields-connection-bridge/). You can buy a pre-assembled one or patch them manually by hand and wire.

Comment: @PandaLion98 bon appeti with your dinner =) There should be no modification of the screen required - just patch it to RPi and use it's codes from the manufacturer's site

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin As OP has stated: "Is it possible to modify 2.4" TFT LCD Shield** to use it via **USB port** on Raspberry Pi to see the desktop, and to touch to control?". Your links use the **GPIO headers** and **not USB**. Kindly re-read the question when in doubt :)

Comment: @PandaLion98 the task it has is two-part. First, OP **must** fire it up through GPIO, *this is the only way for Arduino shields*. After that - [something like this](http://www.robotshop.com/en/devantec-usb-i2c-spi-serial-interface.html) "detaches" a shield from GPIO via USB, and this is a "stage two"

Comment: @AlexeyVesnin Exactly why I said **NO**. OP is referring to directly using the screen **without using any of the things you mentioned**. i.e. He is referring to actually changing the screen's internal circuitry himself, somehow add USB support, then use it via USB. Kindly re-read the question when in doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this [PiTFT 3,5"](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2097)

It uses SPI from GPIO, so it might be possible to follow the install instructions and maybe hook up your display, if you know you way around electrnics. But it might be more easy to get display createt for the Rpi. ;-)